# Ktor Location API: mapping JSON to generic Map object

Tags: ktor

When I use the regular routing API together with GSON, I can deserialize a JSON parameter to a Map<String, Any> with the following code snippet:

```
        post("/books") {
            val request = call.receive<Map<String, Any>>()
            ...
        }
```

In my case request is an instance of com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.

Is there a way to do the same using the Location API? It works fine when I define a data class with concrete members but I can't find a way to use a map. I'm trying it with a couple of things along those lines:

```
@Location ("/books")
<some magic class definition>

fun Application.bookModule() {
    routing {
        post<BookRequest> {
            val request = call.receive<BookRequest>()
            ...
        }
```

but I've not come up with anything that works. Help?

Comment: I can use `call.receive<Map<String, Any>>()` with a standard route and with one from the `Locations` plugin. Could you please explain what actual behavior is in your case?

Comment: I was under the impression that the type that is annotated with @Location needed to be the same that is used for the parameter. That's not the case?
Currently I have

Comment: `@Location ("/books")
data class BookRequest(val title: String, val author: String, val detail: Map<String, Any>)

fun Application.bookModule() {
    routing {
        post<BookRequest> {
            val request = call.receive<Map<String, Any>>()
            println(request)
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }
    }
}`

Comment: When I call this with
`curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
   --data '{"title":"Hitchhiker", "author":"DNA", "detail":{"foo": "bar"}}' \
   http://localhost:8080/books
`
This results in a 404.

When I implement a get request like in the next comment it works.

@AlekseiTirman - thanks for looking into this.

Comment: `fun Application.bookModule() {
    routing {
        get<BookRequest> {
            val books = bookHandler.listBooks()
            val bookRefs = books.map {
                BookListItem(
                    it.title,
                    URLBuilder(locations.href(BookSearchRequest(it.isbn))).build()
                )
            }
            val message = FreeMarkerContent("books/booklist.ftl", mapOf("books" to bookRefs))
            call.respond(message)
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Locations represent path and query parameters of endpoints only, so there is no way to route depending on the request body. Properties of a location class should be mapped to path segments, e.g.

```
@Location ("/books/{title}/{author}") data class BookRequest(
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
)
```

To receive a request body and convert to it an object just use the [ContentNegotiation](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html)﻿ plugin. Here is the example of a server that responds with 200 OK to the `curl -v --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"title":"Hitchhiker", "author":"DNA", "detail":{"foo": "bar"}}' http://localhost:8080/books` request:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.features.*
import io.ktor.gson.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.locations.*
import io.ktor.locations.post
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            gson()
        }
        install(Locations)
        bookModule()
    }.start()
}

fun Application.bookModule() {
    routing {
        post<BookRequest> {
            val request = call.receive<Map<String, Any>>()
            println(request)
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }
    }
}

@Location ("/books") class BookRequest
```

Comment: That makes sense and I have everything working now. Thanks for providing the detailed description.
Do you think it would be useful if I made a pull request that includes this information in the corresponding documentation?

Comment: Yes, if the documentation isn't clear about it.